# XMLHttpRequest for chrome-extension protocol

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm using background page and I need to inject some code into current tab contents.

so I do following:

- define browser_action
- define listener like this `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener`
- calling script loaded by content_scripts via `chrome.tabs.executeScript`

And from page content I need to load html resource from within extensions folder.

but using this XMLHttpRequest gives me error `Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP`

handled by XMLHttpRequest by error `NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101`

So how am I supposed to solve it?

Note: address is like `chrome-extension://someextensionid/file.html`

Comment: Perhaps you can send a request to the background page, which will do the actual data fetching. Then the background page sends this data to the content script.

Comment: and how can I send variable of type DOMDocument via `executeScript` ?

Comment: I thought with "load html resource" you meant the HTML source, which is just a string. If you're referring to external files in the HTML then it may become tricky.

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to load HTML file and add it to document.body via appendChild

Comment: Send the source (a string) to the content script, then you can parse it there with e.g. jQuery, and append certain elements to the body.

Comment: @pimvdb done thanks to your advice, solution in answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using:

```
btoa(loadXHR(chrome.extension.getURL('file.html')))
```

where

- btoa = string to base64
- loadXHR = synchronous xmlhttprequest
- chrome.extension.getURL = resolve address in extension folder

this was done in background_page and passed to script in foreground using

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript
```

and in foreground, script converted string to html-string and dom object

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = atob(tbr);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

where

- document.createElement = creates new "" element
- innerHTML = HTML value of div element, so setting it will create DOM parseable content
- atob = base64 string to decoded version
- document.appendChild = appends div with HTML content to body element

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
btoa(loadXHR(chrome.extension.getURL('file.html')))
```

you should be able to just use:

```
loadXHR('file.html')
```

as `XMLHttpRequest` understands relative path (with root being your extension folder).

Comment: yeah, you're right. But in my case not every file I need to fetch is placed in same folder as background page

Comment: @Marek Doesn't matter, `/` is your extension folder, you can use `/dir1/dir2/file.html` if you like. `chrome.extension.getURL` is useful only for content scripts, inside background page you can use relative paths everywhere.

Comment: in content scripts you can't use chrome.extension.getURL, isn't it?

Comment: @Marek You can, and that's pretty much the only place where it is needed.